# Two functions which call each other recursively

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to define two functions in clojure which recursively call each other? For example, this pair:

```
(defn a [x]
  (if (= 0 x) 0 (b (dec x))))

(defn b [x]
  (if (= 0 x) 0 (a (dec x))))
```

Compilation fails with:

```
Unable to resolve symbol: b in this context
```

Since I haven't defined `b` when I try to call it in `a`.

e.g., in ruby this works fine:

```
def a(x)
  x == 0 ? x : b(x-1)
end

def b(x)
  x == 0 ? x : a(x-1)
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

either:

`(declare b)` ... ; rest of your code can then be used as is

or:

```
(def mutual
 (letfn [(a [ ... ] ...)
         (b [ ... ] ...)]
  [a b]))

(def a (first mutual))
(def b (second mutual))
```

Comment: Makes sense, guess there's a tradeoff for compilation speed that it can't look ahead for function definitions. Thanks to the deleted answer for this link to the docs (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/declare)

Comment: The tradeoff is not for compilation speed, but catching errors. There is also the `resolve` function when two namespaces need to mutually refer to one another.

Comment: Do you have a link for more info about that? What type of errors are being avoided by the compiler ignoring explicit function definitions?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I was thinking about the code as if entered one form at a time in a repl (where lookahead would be impossible), not loaded from a file. It could be that the behavior has to do with making repl and file behavior identical actually.

Comment: Hmm, well regardless you answered my question :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Also, you can get docs for any function, macro, or special form with the `clojure.repl/doc` macro -- `(doc declare)` `(doc letfn)` `(doc resolve)` (clojure.repl is loaded in the lein repl task by default)

Comment: Is there a reason to declare the intermediate `mutual` value as opposed to something like this? `(letfn [(a [ ... ] ...) (b [ ... ] ...)] (def a a) (def b b))`

Comment: def inside other forms raises suspicion (often a sign of bad design). In this case it would be acceptable, I have a knee jerk to avoid it because when I see it I slow down and wonder why it is there.

Comment: nice, so both my "catching errors" and repl-orientation hunches were correct!

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the execution of your code, keep in mind that you might get stack overflow exception.

There is where (clojure.core/trampoline) function come into the play and do its magic.

> trampoline can be used to convert algorithms requiring mutual
>   recursion without stack consumption. Calls f with supplied args, if
>   any. If f returns a fn, calls that fn with no arguments, and
>   continues to repeat, until the return value is not a fn, then
>   returns that non-fn value. Note that if you want to return a fn as a
>   final value, you must wrap it in some data structure and unpack it
>   after trampoline returns.

Comment: ha! the first blog post I found about this even used my example functions: http://pramode.net/clojure/2010/05/08/clojure-trampoline/